# muliple subdomains dns levels working

Tags: dns

In this moment, I am learning how the DNS and domains resolutions work and I have a question.

Let's take `a.test.com` for example.

As I understand it, first of all, the intermediary ISP DNS server is called. If it has the domain IP in cache, it returns it. Otherwise, it does consecutively these following tasks :

- It calls a **root DNS server** which returns a **com** DNS server IP
- It calls that **top level DNS server** which returns the **test.com** DNS server IP
- It calls that **DNS server** to finally get **a.test.com**'s IP

Is it correct ?

And now what does it happen when we resolve `a.b.c.test.com` ?
Does it call another DNS server or does the `c.test.com`'s DNS server contain the `a.b.c.test.com`'s IP ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are pretty much correct. Nothing different will happen in next steps: `c.test.com` will respond with a referral to more authoritative server (the one for `b.c.test.com`), or if itself is authoritative then it will respond with an answer.

Comment: so, to get a.b.c.test.com's IP, the following requests to those servers will be done : (m.)root-servers.com, com's DNS server, test.com DNS server, c.test.com DNS, b.c.test.com DNS, a.b.c.test.com DNS (which will return the final IP address) ? Consider that there is no DNS cache

Comment: It could be, but not necessarily. It would be quite common that name server that is authoritative for `test.com` zone can also give authoritative answer for `a.b.c.test.com` so none of the steps after third would happen. Try `dig a.b.c.d.e.bajic.nl @8.8.8.8 +trace` for the example.

Comment: Ok, that situation is common because in most of the case the authoritative server for `test.com` contains also a A record for `a.b.c.test.com` (and all the sub domains) ?
By authoritative name server for `test.com`, you mean the one which returns `test.com`'s IP address ?

Comment: Server is authoritative for the zone if it stores the zone data in its configuration (it can give answers without need to contact any other server).

Comment: And to answer your first question: yes, an organization may have many domains and subdomains, but keep them all on couple of DNS servers.

Comment: so the DNS server for `test.com` is authoritative if it stores records (A, CNAME, etc) and can return the IP of `test.com` (without contacting another server) right ?
Ok and next question, is there another caching system **excluding the ISP one** ? I guess yes but how do those cache system work ?

Comment: Right. About the caching, I am not sure what do you mean by "ISP caching system", but basically all servers will cache received responses for a period of time determined by TTL value associated with the record in response.

Comment: I meant the ISP's DNS server (which also has a cache).
Ok, is there a way to see immediately the changes on a domain after changing the DNS zone ?
And what does Cloudflare do ? As I understood, it replaces `test.com` DNS's server. How come that it also hides the real IP address ?

Comment: You can see the changes immediately if you query the authoritative server, but other users will use their own server, and it (and its upstream servers probably) will have cached old data which you can't do nothing about, except to wait for TTL to expire. This is what is sometimes known as "DNS propagation" (which is I think wrong name). I am not familiar with Cloudflare though.